# Websphere 6.1 to 7.0 JmqiObject and JmsQueue missing

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-6.1, websphere-7

I am trying to migrate an application from Websphere 6.1 to 7.0

I noticed that many of the ibm MQ/JMS classes have changed/disappeared =)

In particular, I am getting errors on

com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsQueue
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiObject

it is saying "...cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Does anyone know what I can do to get this to compile?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to say exactly from the description so I'll provide some general pointers that may be of help.

The WMQ JMS and Java support was completely rewritten in V7 to use a common JMQI layer.  This will affect the jar files that are referenced as well as the CLASSPATH and a few other things.

If you have bundled the WMQ jar files into your application, you will want to delete them and reference the ones installed with WAS instead.

If you used MDB listeners, you will need to switch to Activation Specs.

For more info, see the *[Integration of WebSphere MQ classes for JMS with WebSphere Application Server](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi21350_.htm)* section in the [WMQ V7 Migration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi10120_.htm) manual and the CLASSPATH settings from the *[Environment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10330_.htm)* section in the *[WMQ V7 Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10120_.htm)* manual.

The *[WebSphere Application Server V7 Migration Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4635.html?Open)* does not address WMQ in depth but it does have pointers to additional migration resources such as IBM Education Assistant as well as specific application and profile migration advice.