# The type com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsQueue cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, message-queue

I am trying to set up MQ on WAS v7.0 in RAD 8 using QueueConnection and QueueConnectionFactory classes. I am getting a compile error in one of the class "The type com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsQueue cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files". Could someone please help me out this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add WebSphere 7.0 server runtime into Java build path. In RAD 8 right click on procject where you see this error, and then select Build Path -> Configure Build Path, then select tab "Libraries" and click on "Add Library", in next window select "Server Runtime" and on next screen select "WebSphere Application Server 7.0".

Comment: Thanks Magic for the response. But in my build path, WAS v7.0 is already selected and even the JRE System Library is v7.0 JRE.

Comment: Do you bundle WMQ JMS JAR into your application? If the answer is yes, then remove it and use the ones that came with WebSphere. This question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215486/websphere-6-1-to-7-0-jmqiobject-and-jmsqueue-missing